# Is it possible to dynamically type the output of a function using the name of the function parameter as the property of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to dynamically type the output of a function using the name of the input parameter with an existing interface:

```
interface MyInterface {
  typeA: string;
  typeB: boolean;
  typeC: string;
  typeD: number;
  ...
}

const myFunction: (parameterName: string) => MyInterface[parameterName] =
  (parameterName) =>
    {
      ...
      return valueXYZ 
    }
```

I get this error:

*'parameterName' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.*

Currently my this way defined variables have all to implement their specific type on their own and I can't type my function in a more general way as shown above.

```
const valueA: MyInterface['typeA'] = myFunction('typeA');
const valueB: MyInterface['typeB'] = myFunction('typeB');
const valueC: MyInterface['typeC'] = myFunction('typeC');
const valueD: MyInterface['typeD'] = myFunction('typeD');
...
```

Is there a way to tell Typescript to use the parameterName as the propertyName that's defined in the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your parameter to define the output value of your function you can do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  typeA: string;
  typeB: boolean;
  typeC: string;
  typeD: number;
}

const myFunction = <T extends keyof MyInterface>(parameterName: T): MyInterface[T] => {
  ...implementation
}

const test = myFunction('typeB'); // typeof test is boolean
const test = myFunction('typeD'); // typeof test is number
const test = myFunction('unknown'); // error, unknown is not in MyInterface
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't really get why you have to add 'T' to the parameterName as well, but that works.
Afterwards if you want to use parameterName in the function you have to explicitly type it as string again:

`myObject[parameterName as string]`

Comment: T is here so you can only put valid parameter names (thats the example with unknown). Actually you don't need to do that if you specify in your tsconfig: "keyofStringsOnly": true . but that may effect other things

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Foo {
   bar: Bar;
   baz: Baz;
}

function myFunction<T extends keyof Foo>(param: T): Foo[T] {
  ...
}

const bar = myFunction('bar');
// bar: Bar
const baz = myFunction('baz');
// baz: Baz
```